# Double exclamation is shown before doctype tag in rendered DOM

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have made a view in codeigniter and loaded that view from controller. But double exclamation is always shown before `doctype` tag.

Like this:

[image: !! is appended before meta tag.]

When I view source from browser I can see

[image: !! can be seen while doing view page source]

How can I remove `!!` from my webpage? Please help me.

Comment: it could be a lot of different things. so make a new view file from a new blank document and see if it happens.

Comment: if I work on a normal html file, it works fine. But when I use PHP the problem persists. However, I can run the view with PHP in localhost successfully without any problem. Whenever I upload it to server, I get the same problem

Comment: you are just going to have to track it down. at some point i usually do a 'sanity check' - download a fresh new copy of codeigniter. upload to your server. see if its on the default welcome page.

Comment: http://reeteshghimire.com.np/Untitled.png This is shown while inspecting in chrome. Please help me.

Comment: did you upload a fresh copy of codeigniter?

Comment: yes I did upload a fresh copy

Comment: *"How can I remove `!!` from my webpage?  Please help me."* ~ **Show us the code** from your view file.

Comment: wow seriously you uploaded a new copy of codeigniter and you are still getting that error. ok - next try a plain php file - not inside codeigniter - like test.php If it appears on there then there is something messed up with your hosting account.

Comment: actually - when you uploaded the new copy of codeigniter - did this appear on the default welcome page??? if yes then do the test i mentioned above.

Comment: function index()
{
 echo 'Hello World';
}          This is the index function inside welcome controller which is the default controller. Still I get the output as !!Hello World. I guess it is not the problem with view file.

Comment: Also on each ajax call in my project, '!!' is prepended to every ajax response.